# Developing a right-to-left Android application

Tags: android, right-to-left

I'm working on a relatively simple Android app. I want it to have an English version as well as a Hebrew version.

I have an activity all laid out in English, and I want to create the Hebrew resources. I couldn't find any easy way to do it. The only way I found was to take my layout/activity.xml file, put it in layout-iw/activity.xml and manually change everything so it appears right to left.

I need to reverse the order of all elements in any horizontally oriented container (all the columns in `<TableRow>`s, all the elements in horizontal `<LinearLayout>`s, etc...). I need to switch all layout_marginLefts with layout_marginRights, and of course - make all left-aligned controls right-aligned.

This is tedious, especially if I think about modifying the activity at some point - I'll need to modify the resources twice, and that alone gives me a headache.

There *has* to be an easier way.

Comment: If all else fails, my next question would be about the appropriate place to hook a mechanism that will do this automatically. I guess I'll call it RtlAwareActivity or something. I *really* don't want to write this.

Comment: I don't suspect there is going to be a packaged solution for this as there will probably be a lot of layout issues that arise from this change, in general that is. So it wouldn't really be safe to make an all in one solution to this. I believe TextViews will automatically render right to left, but that's about it. FWIW, I think it might be better for you to just generate the layout xmls with a precompile hook rather than write an activity to do it on the fly. That way there is no runtime overhead.

Comment: I am pro Microsoft but any way they did a really good job on WPF!!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are correct this is exactly what you will have to do.
I would suggest using [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to format any elements where padding or margins need to change do to a switch from left to right text. If you construct your styles right it should limit the amount of line by line changes needed in individual layout files. However I do realize this is a case where hind-site is 20/20.